# How to build a web widget with PHP, Java Script and give custom CSS controls to external sites?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, widget

I am trying to create a web widget that can be easily integrated into any website by just copying a small piece of code but most importantly give the user **custom CSS controls** like changing the font or button color, etc. My code consists of JavaScript and PHP. I tried to do this with `<iframe>` but it just copies the whole page with menu and footer. I couldn't find any solution on how to remove it. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I am sorry for that, I updated the question.